getting 0xBAADF00D and not getting all data when assembling a file
I made 16 bit a computer in logisim and want to assemble some code for it but when that i don't get all that data and i get BAAD FOOD BAAD FOOD BAAD
my assembly code is:
ADD 3 3 3
and i want to get:
1300 0003 0003 0003
but i get
1300 0003 0003 BAAD F00D BAAD F00D BAAD
my code is:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Node {
    int16_t value;
    struct Node* next;
} Node;

int linkedListSize(Node* start){
    int size = 0;
    Node* curr = start;
    while (curr!= NULL){
        size++;
        if (curr -> next == 0xbaadf00dbaadf00d) break;
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    return size;
}

int isDigit(char *string, int size){
    char *digits = "0123456789";
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i ++){
        int in = 0;
        for (int x = 0; x < 10; x ++){
            if (string[i] == digits[x]){
                in = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (in == 0){
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

// Corrected to accept the length of the string as an argument
int toDigit(char *string, int len){
    char *digits = "0123456789";
    int value = 0;
    int neg = string[0] == '-';
    for (int i = neg; i < len; i++){
        for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++){
            if (string[i] == digits[x]){
                value *= 10;
                value += x;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (neg) value = -value;
    return value;
}

// Corrected to return a dynamically allocated array
int16_t* makeLikedList(Node* start){
    int size = linkedListSize(start);
    int16_t *list = (int16_t *)malloc(size * 16);

    int idx = 0;
    Node* curr = start;
    while (curr != NULL){
        if (curr -> next == 0xbaadf00dbaadf00d) break;
        list[idx] = curr->value;
        idx ++;
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    return list;
}

// Corrected loop condition
char *stringToYFromX(char *string, int x, int y){
    char *newString = (char *)malloc(y-x+1); // Allocate space for the null terminator
    for (int i = x; i < y; i++){
        newString[i-x] = string[i];
    }
    newString[y-x] = '\0'; // Ensure the string is null-terminated
    return newString;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    if (argc!= 3){
        printf("Error: invalid args\n");
        return 1;
    }
    FILE *assemblyFile;
    int assemblySize;
    char *assemblyCode;
    assemblyFile = fopen(argv[1],"rb");
    
    fseek(assemblyFile, 0, SEEK_END); 
    assemblySize = ftell(assemblyFile);
    fseek(assemblyFile, 0, SEEK_SET); 

    assemblyCode = (char*) malloc(assemblySize + 1);
    fread(assemblyCode, 1, assemblySize, assemblyFile);
    assemblyCode[assemblySize] = '\0';   

    FILE *binFile;
    Node* binListStart = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    binFile = fopen(argv[2],"wb");

    char *curr;
    int currSize = 0;
    int currStart = 0;
    int count = 0;
    Node* opNode;
    Node* currNode = binListStart;
    for (int i = 0; i < assemblySize; i ++){
        if (assemblyCode[i] == ' '){
            count += 1;
            if ((count - 1) % 4 == 0){
                opNode = currNode;
            }
            curr = (char*) malloc(currSize + 1);
            for (int x = 0; x < currSize; x++){
                curr[x] = assemblyCode[currStart+x];
            }
            curr[currSize] = '\0';
            if (strcmp(curr,"ADD")==0){
                currNode -> value = 0x1000;
                currNode->next = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
            } else if (strcmp(curr,"SUB")==0){
                currNode -> value = 0x1001;
                currNode->next = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
            } else if (strcmp(curr,"MUL")==0){
                currNode -> value = 0x1002;
                currNode->next = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
            } else if (strcmp(curr,"DIV")==0){
                currNode -> value = 0x1003;
                currNode->next = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
            } else if (strcmp(curr,"MOD")==0){
                currNode -> value = 0x1004;
                currNode->next = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
            } else if (strcmp(curr,"SHL")==0){
                currNode -> value = 0x1005;
                currNode->next = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
            } else if (strcmp(curr,"SHR")==0){
                currNode -> value = 0x1006;
                currNode->next = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
            } else if (strcmp(curr,"ASHR")==0){
                currNode -> value = 0x1008;
                currNode->next = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
            } else if (strcmp(curr,"RSHL")==0){
                currNode -> value = 0x1009;
                currNode->next = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
            } else if (strcmp(curr,"RSHR")==0){
                currNode -> value = 0x100a;
                currNode->next = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
            } else if (strcmp(curr,"AND")==0){
                currNode -> value = 0x100b;
                currNode->next = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
            } else if (strcmp(curr,"OR")==0){
                currNode -> value = 0x100c;
                currNode->next = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
            } else if (strcmp(curr,"XOR")==0){
                currNode -> value = 0x100d;
                currNode->next = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
            } else if (strcmp(curr,"NOT")==0){
                currNode -> value = 0x100e;
                currNode->next = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
            } else if (strcmp(curr,"NAND")==0){
                currNode -> value = 0x100f;
                currNode->next = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
            } else if (strcmp(curr,"NOR")==0){
                currNode -> value = 0x1010;
                currNode->next = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
            } else if (strcmp(curr,"XNOR")==0){
                currNode -> value = 0x1011;
                currNode->next = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
            } else if (strcmp(curr,"JE")==0){
                currNode -> value = 0x2000;
                currNode->next = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
            } else if (strcmp(curr,"JNE")==0){
                currNode -> value = 0x2001;
                currNode->next = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
            } else if (strcmp(curr,"JL")==0){
                currNode -> value = 0x2002;
                currNode->next = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
            } else if (strcmp(curr,"JG")==0){
                currNode -> value = 0x2003;
                currNode->next = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
            } else if (strcmp(curr,"JLE")==0){
                currNode -> value = 0x2004;
                currNode->next = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
            } else if (strcmp(curr,"JGE")==0){
                currNode -> value = 0x2005;
                currNode->next = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
            } else if (strcmp(curr,"LOAD")==0){
                currNode -> value = 0x3000;
                currNode->next = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
            } else if (strcmp(curr,"MOV")==0){
                currNode -> value = 0x3001;
                currNode->next = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
            } else if (strcmp(curr,"RLD")==0){
                currNode -> value = 0x4000;
                currNode->next = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
            } else if (strcmp(curr,"RMV")==0){
                currNode -> value = 0x4001;
                currNode->next = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
            } else if (strcmp(curr,"RGT")==0){
                currNode -> value = 0x4002;
                currNode->next = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
            } else if (strcmp(curr,"PUSH")==0){
                currNode -> value = 0x5000;
                currNode->next = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
            } else if (strcmp(curr,"POP")==0){
                currNode -> value = 0x5001;
                currNode->next = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
            } else if (isDigit(curr,currSize) == 1){
                if ((count - 1) % 4 == 0){
                    printf("Error: invalid token\ntoken number: %d\ntoken: %s",count,curr);
                    return 1;
                }
                switch ((count - 1) % 4)
                {
                case 1:
                    opNode->value += 0x0100;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    opNode->value += 0x0200;
                    break;
                }
                currNode -> value = toDigit(curr,currSize);
                currNode->next = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
            } else if (curr[0] == 'r'){
                curr = stringToYFromX(curr,1,currSize);
                if ((count - 1) % 4 == 3 && isDigit(curr,currSize) == 0){
                    printf("Error: invalid token\ntoken number: %d\ntoken: r%s",count,curr);
                    return 1;
                }
                currNode -> value = toDigit(curr,currSize);
                currNode->next = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
            } else {
                printf("Error: invalid token\ntoken number: %d\ntoken: %s",count,curr);
                return 1;
            }
            currNode = currNode -> next;
            curr = NULL;
            currSize = 0;
            currStart = i+1;
        }
        else{
            currSize ++;
        }
    }
    fwrite(makeLikedList(binListStart), sizeof(int), linkedListSize(binListStart), binFile);
    fclose(assemblyFile);
    fclose(binFile);
}


I tried adding buffers to stop baadfood in my linked list functions. BAADf00D also seems to be what the Null is.

Why do you have curr -> next == 0xbaadf00dbaadf00d? Is it just because of this issue?

Other than that, please learn how to debug your programs. Like using a debugger to step through the code line by line while monitoring variables and their values.

And as a general tip: Don't write large patches of code all at once. Instead start with an empty main function. Build with extra warnings enabled, and treated as errors. When it builds cleanly, test the program in all possible ways. Only when all tests passes, add a very small bit of code, perhaps even just one or two lines. If you do it like that, it will be very easy to detect problems, and to isolate them into a [mre] which you can easily debug.

Ok, there is only one thing you really need to do to make it not crash.
In main just after you:
currNode = currNode -> next;

You also need to add:
currNode -> next = NULL;

So that the next item is pointing to NULL.
If you don't it will be pointing to a random location.
Which on your non-release compile is 0xBAADFOOD
Then if you turn on the memory address sanitizer it will complains that all the memory you have malloced hasn't been freed.  So, you need to do that as well.
Here is a working copy: https://onlinegdb.com/-SnvBEZUa8
If you add this to your code:
OpCode opCodes[] = {
    {"ADD",  0x1000},{"SUB",  0x1001},{"MUL",  0x1002},{"DIV",  0x1003},{"MOD",  0x1004},
    {"SHL",  0x1005},{"SHR",  0x1006},{"ASHR", 0x1008},{"RSHL", 0x1009},{"RSHR", 0x100a},
    {"AND",  0x100b},{"OR",   0x100c},{"XOR",  0x100d},{"NOT",  0x100e},{"NAND", 0x100f},
    {"NOR",  0x1010},{"XNOR", 0x1011},{"JE",   0x2000},{"JNE",  0x2001},{"JL",   0x2002},
    {"JG",   0x2003},{"JLE",  0x2004},{"JGE",  0x2005},{"LOAD", 0x3000},{"MOV",  0x3001},
    {"RLD",  0x4000},{"RMV",  0x4001},{"RGT",  0x4002},{"PUSH", 0x5000},{"POP",  0x5001},
};
int16_t opCodesSize = sizeof(opCodes)/sizeof(OpCode);

int16_t findOpCodeValue(const char *opCode){
    for(int i = 0; i < opCodesSize; i++){
        if (strcmp(opCodes[i].name, opCode)==0){
            return opCodes[i].value;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

Then you can replace all the if statements checking for opcodes with:
int16_t value = findOpCodeValue(curr);
if (value > -1){
    currNode -> value = value;
    currNode->next = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
}

And the code will be much shorter and easier to read.
You can try that here: https://onlinegdb.com/1dDgzqZGg

That fixes the 0xBAADF00D but i get 7bc0 21f3 0237 0000 at the end

@Lpow100 so that must be a logic problem...  My code in the link generates 1300 0003 0003 0000 which still doesn't match your requested result (the last number is 0000 instead of 0003).  If you add printf("0x%04X ",curr->value); just before list[idx++] = curr->value; it will print the values it is putting into list. https://onlinegdb.com/OKH1wtJq-
